# Need help adding carthage dependencies to a React Native package I am authoring

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, carthage

I need to build a wrapper around code that has dependencies that are only available as Carthage dependencies. I have successfully added them to a standard tvOS swift project. I am authoring a react-native ui component in swift with the help of the [create-react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) package by Callstack.

I added a cartfile in the same way as in my swift project, but this time in the iOS folder of the actual react-native package I am authoring. Here, carthage updates and builds the dependencies correctly, but they do not compile. There is no way to add the generated xc-frameworks to the package's Xcode project file (there are no options to add frameworks in the package project, only in the embedded example project).

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to proceed with this?

Comment: RN's preferred package management solution seems to be CocoaPods -- is there a reason that you want to use Carthage instead?

Comment: Yes - the company for whom I am building the package uses Carthage